# How to redirect back to my app page from github

Tags: python, django, github-api

I am writing a view in django so that it take a user to github and get access of their repositories and all.

```
import requests
def Authenticated_user(request):
  if request.method == 'GET':
    req = requests.get('https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize',
        params = {
            'client_id': 'something',
            'redirect_uri': 'localhost:8000/app/',
            'scope': 'user,public_repo,user:email.user:follow',
        }
    )
    content = req.content
  return HttpResponse(content)
```

this is taking me to login page but the problem is when I logged in, it redirects me to `http://localhost:8000/session` instead of `http://localhost:8000/app/`.
I tried this also

```
req = requests.get('https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=something&redirect_uri=localhost:8000/app&scope=something,something
```

but getting the same result. 
I am not getting what's the problem is. please help me. 
And also I want to know how to use that "code" for oauth2 which I will get after successfully logging in.

Comment: did you try `http://localhost:8000/app/` ?

Comment: Also, what did you define as the callback URL in the GitHub settings for your OAuth application?

Comment: @doniyor Yeah I have tried `http://localhost:8000/app/` also. still getting the same result

Comment: @IvanZuzak I have provided the same `http://localhost:8000/app/` as callback URL in the Github settings.

Comment: @TasneemHaider please show us your urls.py, you might have a wrong regexp'ing

Comment: @doniyor `url(r'^app/', include('app.urls')),` and in app/urls.py `url('^profile/$', views.profile, name='profile'), url('^profile/repo/$', views.Authenticated_user, name='repo'),`